# Битрикс: как добавить товар со своей ценой?

Tags: битрикс, корзина

Цена изменяется в карточке товара. Как эту цену подменить на ту что в базе? Пробовал OnBeforeBasketAdd, не получается. Также изменение товара не в любом случае должно происходить, если цена поменялась в карточке, то надо загрузить эту цену, а если нет то загрузить стандартную

Answer (score 0):

Я так понимаю вы хотите кастомную цену указывать на товар при добавлении товара в корзину. Для этого, вам лучше всего надо будет написать свой провайдер цен и при добавлении товара в корзину, указывать класс своего провайдера цен. Т.к. при пересчете битрикс использует логику из провайдера цен класса указанного на товаре при добавлении товара в корзину.
Более детально можете почитать [тут](https://github.com/SidiGi/bitrix-info/wiki/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B7%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%83-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-(D7)#%D0%9C%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4-3-%D0%A1%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80-%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BD)

Comment: Это я уже видел спасибо. На самом деле нужна цена для другого типа пользователей. Эта функция почему то не работает хотя я создал тип цены и тип пользовтелей и связал их и прописал цену в тлваре и сделал этот тип цены видимым, но его не видно а когда выбираю только его то пустое поле. Получается менять через скидку но скидка меняет только вывод цены, при попадании в корзину цена старая! В массиве minimal_price на value старая цена, а скидка на discount. Можете обьяснить как цену из скидки послать в корзину?